# WP REST API, no data is fetched

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, api

I'm totally new this API, OAuth stuff in WordPress and I'm trying to list all the users as a JSON and make them usable in a client app.

What I did was installing this little plugin [WP REST API (WP API)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) and trying to list a user via the address `mysite.com/wp-json/users/4`. But, it just gives me this message

`[{"code":"json_user_cannot_list","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to list users."}]`

I did changed Permalinks too. But no luck!

What's wrong in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the plugin are you using as according to its documentation, version 2 can access files like that

Answer (score 0):

Use version 2 whose link is https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/ this will enable querying that way.You can also read the version one description for more details

Answer (score 0):

implement `get_user()` method of `WP_REST_CONTROLLER`

```
protected function get_user() {

        $error = new WP_Error(
            'rest_user_invalid_id',
            __( 'Invalid user ID.' ),
            array( 'status' => 404 )
        );

        // if ( (int) $id <= 0 ) {
        //  return $error;
        // }

        // $user = get_userdata($user_email);
        // if ( empty( $user ) || ! $user->exists() ) {
        //  return $error;
        // }

        // if ( is_multisite() && ! is_user_member_of_blog( $user->ID ) ) {
        //  return $error;
        // }

        return $user;
    }
```